# Socket.io, Mongodb - Right way to implement chatroom and organise database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I'm new in Node.js and want to build a chatroom with Socket.io. I could implement simple chat and want to improve that. 
For easy to imagine, I would like to build a chatroom like Facebook Messenger, in which people can talk to others or create a group chat.
I researched many topics but haven't understood how to solve my problem.

Some people give me some ways like that:

Client:

```
socket.on('connect', () => {
    socket.emit('join', roomId); // don't know how to create unique roomId
    // that server can grab it
});

btnSend.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // data: { senderId: [string], receiverId: [array of receiver], msg: [string] }
    socket.emit('send message', data);
});

socket.on('new message', (data) => {
    // append to body
});
```

Server:

```
socket.on('join', (roomId) => {
    socket.join(`room ${ roomId }`, () => {
       console.log(`in room ${ roomId }`);
    });

    socket.on('send message', (data) => {
        // save to db
        socket.in(roomId).emit('new message', data);
    });
});
```

Now I stuck at:

1. **How to manage rooms and people in there? How to create dynamic `roomId`?**
   Socket.io has `socket.rooms` (contains `socket.id` and `roomId`) but each time a user load or reload the page, a new `socket.id` is generated, so I can't use it. When a user talks to someone, they create a new room. I don't know how to notify the server to create roomId.

Example: There are three clients: A, B, C.

A want to talk to B, so the server must create a room for A and B.

A want to talk to C, so the server must create a room for A and C.

**When someone disconnects then connect again, how to connect them to existed room?** Use session, variable or db to store `roomId`? But when the server is downed how to restore them?

2. I'm using Mongodb as my database, which contains two collections are `user` and `dialog`. I stuck at organise db structure of `dialog`. I use

   `{
   _id: string,
   sender: { id: string, name: string },
   receiver: [
     { id: string, name: string },
     { id: string, name: string },
     ...
   ],
   msg: string,
   created: time
   }`

   but for now people can be in a group, should I add `group` field?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can make a variable, `lastId` , and then asign `lastId++` to each new room, so each room will have an id 1 bigger than the last.
2. The client may store the roomId it joined in the `localStorage`, so it will be remembered.
3. Don't create rooms in .on("connect"), make a button or something that creates rooms, and maybe only join rooms automatically if an id is found in `localStorage`
4. a group field may be needed to query only the useful messages

Useful links:

- localStorage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Seems you mean that the server creates rooms then the client save them? 
`lastId` var will be deleted if server down
If a user messages to another, the server should create a room for them automatically, but if I use `localStorage`, because `lastId` increases value, each user has different id!

Comment: Dont create rooms on connect. At start, users dont rly need to be in any room if nothing is found in localstorage. Only create rooms if the users wants to (like a button or something)